# NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate views not filled with predicate

Tags: cocoa, nspredicateeditor

I have an `NSPredicateEditor` for which I'm setting up custom template row views.

The templates generate the correct predicate, but when I set the editor's `objectValue` to display the predicate, the views are not filling.  The templates' `matchForPredicate` functions are working correctly, and the correct template is getting the `setPredicate` message sent by the editor after I've set the editor's `objectValue`, but nothing further is happening.  Right now, the templates' `setPredicate` function simply calls `super`, but I've not seen anything out there that I should do anything differently.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the (simplified) code of the RowTemplate subclass.

Answer (score 0):

This was a retain problem;  once that was fixed, everything worked as expected.